# Rename output file to other package

Tags: bazel

I have a label `//foo_base:bar`, which produces a `foo_base/bar_0_8_9.tar`.
Now I need to have this also as `foo_concrete/bar.tar` (in package `//foo_concrete`).

This should be possible by writing some action that does copy of the file. But this seems excessive. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a genrule to create a symlink:

```
genrule(
    name = "make_bar_tar",
    srcs = ["//foo_base:bar"],
    outs = ["bar.tar"],
    cmd = "ln -s $(location //foo_base:bar) $@")
```

Comment: Question is _a_, whether this can be done more platform-agnostic and _b_, whether this makes problems since the timestamp of `bar.tar` will always match `//foo_base:bar`.

Comment: Copying the file is probably the only easy way to make it cross platform. But, if you are concerned about the timestamp, copying the file would be worse: then the timestamp is always different. I think the easiest thing is not to depend on the timestamp.

Comment: The timestamp doesn't matter. Bazel detects if `//foo_base:bar` is changed and will rebuild `make_bar_tar` and thus `bar.tar` in the next build as necessary.